# How to construct an Amazon S3 URI given bucket name and key?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Given bucket name and key, how do I get `s3://bucket-name/key` without using simple String operations? Is there a method in AmazonS3URI?

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no such method available. You can simply construct the string yourself (which is much easier than making an API call):

```
https://bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com/key
```

Answer (score 0):

### To simply construct valid s3:// URL

You can use java.net.URL class:

```
URL urlObject = new URL("s3","bucket-name,"key");
System.out.println(urlObject);
```

[javaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URL.html)

### To Create http url of s3 object accessible via http request

```
 S3Client s3client = S3Client.create();
 S3Utilities utilities = s3client.utilities();
 GetUrlRequest request = GetUrlRequest.builder().bucket("bucket-name").key("key").build();
 URL url = utilities.getUrl(request);
```

[javaDoc](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/s3/S3Utilities.html)